# Extended Client missing functions

Tags: typescript, discord.js, typescript-typings

I am currently working, on a rewrite of my discord bot from js to ts.
To use typing, I extend the discord.js client, I can not fetch channels and send a message there. How can I work around this, besides using type:any?

my extended client:

```
export class DiscordClient extends Client {
    commands
    config
}
```

This does not work anymore with the `Client` type set to `DiscordClient`.
If I set it to any, it works just fine

```
client.channels.cache
        .find((channel) => channel.id == client.config.ids.channelIDs.dev.botTestLobby)
        .send({ embeds: [loginMessage] })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be many types of channels (text, voice, etc.), and TypeScript doesn't know which type of channel you're `.find`ing, and not every channel type has the `.send` function (you can't send messages in voice channels).

To go around this, if you're sure the channel ID you've stored in your `client.config` is a text channel ID, you can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to change that variable's type to `TextChannel`.

Here's how it would look:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.id == client.config.ids.channelIDs.dev.botTestLobby) as TextChannel
channel.send({ embeds: [loginMessage] })
```